Firebase Crashlytic: Number of crashed user in trends table is differrence number of crashed user in crash free user table
enter image description here
I'm monitoring health of my application. However, I realize that number of crashed user in Trends table is difference number of crashed user in Crash-free users table (in the explanation when hovering over the ?).
Besides i noticed that number of crash free user in Crashlytic is still differece number of crash free user in Google analytic in the same time range.
Please explain to me. Thank you!
I have researched on internet so i can not find any document which explain this problem
